# SVG as background in google chrome not displaying

Tags: html, css, svg

html:

```
`<a href="https://somelink" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank" class="btn popupLogo btn-link btn-xs"></a>`
```

css:

```
.popupLogo {
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
background: center no-repeat url(../img/logo.svg);
}
```

google chrome is not displaying the svg, I've tried also to use `object`, but as a result the svg is downloaded, but not displayed, is there a workable solution?

Comment: Have you set the link to be inline-block? We'd need to **see** this not working to judge. Can you make a demo?

Comment: If the SVG is downloaded rather than displayed then you're almost certainly serving it with the wrong mime-type.

Comment: Same. Weirdly enough loading the SVG as url and then reloading the page works. Also no problems in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that (in my case) Chrome sometimes has problems when you write few statements in one css command like: `background: center no-repeat url(../img/logo.svg);`

Try it like this:

```
background-image: url("../img/logo.svg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: so maybe the link to the picture is wrong? does it show in other browsers? i recommend doing a JSFiddle so it's easier for us to help.